# Nested grid is not taking full height of his parent grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I have this problem that I am not sure is related to CSS grid. I want a layout with a fixed footer like this.

[image]

The problem that I am facing is that when the content on RIGHT or LEFT is bigger than their parents, the parent doesn't increase in height and I end with this. I would like to have both LEFT and RIGHT sections increase in height according to their contents so their respective background-colors are visible.
[image]

```css
#app {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
  grid-template-areas: 'main' 'footer';
}

#app main {
  grid-area: main;
  overflow: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-rows: 100%;
  grid-template-areas: 'left right';
  background-color: red;
}

#app main .main-left {
  grid-area: left;
  background-color: #ff8127;
  border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 70% 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100%;
}

#app main .main-left .logo {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 4;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 90%;
  width: fit-content;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}

#app main .main-left .text-logo {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
  display: grid;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: black;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 300px;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#app main .main-left .text-logo .text {
  display: grid;
}

#app main .main-left .text-logo p {
  margin: 1.5em 0;
}

#app main .main-right {
  grid-area: right;
  background-color: blue;
  border-left: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

#app footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  padding: 13px;
  font-size: 13px;
  background-color: white;
  border-top: 2px solid #e5e5e5;
}

#app footer p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  color: #5a5a5a;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <main>
      <section class="main-left">
        <img class="logo" src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/505/824/png-transparent-logo-drawing-lion-lion-illustration-vertebrate-flower-fictional-character.png" alt="logo" />
        <div class="text-logo">
          <div class="text">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi doloribus fugit sunt at iste, dignissimos quam voluptas adipisci illo rerum maxime quis incidunt consequatur corporis velit maiores minima laboriosam. Iusto! Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur
              adipisicing elit. Odit beatae veniam sed eveniet molestiae deleniti modi nostrum, obcaecati perferendis sapiente similique totam voluptatem eos corporis minus libero, et cumque aperiam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
              elit. Amet ab enim inventore illum voluptas, quaerat possimus aliquid natus? Corporis cumque quas sit. Ullam distinctio doloribus molestiae nihil reiciendis? Ut, sequi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis maxime
              porro, quibusdam iure provident esse nam, eius veritatis autem facilis officia dolorum iusto culpa eveniet corrupti facere deserunt ipsam voluptate. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi reiciendis, architecto
              aperiam nisi minus necessitatibus doloribus ad aut vitae libero impedit quidem illo mollitia obcaecati repudiandae temporibus voluptate quam! Nobis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et, cupiditate perferendis. Saepe
              illo quas ab quo veniam voluptas voluptatem ad architecto quia. Dolore quisquam molestias illo debitis voluptatum nesciunt repellendus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum suscipit animi sunt natus quae hic dolorem
              distinctio, laboriosam itaque dolorum vitae nihil cum voluptatem dolores ea, delectus repudiandae ducimus non. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat quo iste nulla magni et. Accusantium ex, voluptatibus blanditiis
              mollitia architecto accusamus necessitatibus quisquam tempora enim, ea, sint laborum quos adipisci? Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi doloribus fugit sunt at iste, dignissimos quam voluptas adipisci illo rerum
              maxime quis incidunt consequatur corporis velit maiores minima laboriosam. Iusto! Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit beatae veniam sed eveniet molestiae deleniti modi nostrum, obcaecati perferendis sapiente similique
              totam voluptatem eos corporis minus libero, et cumque aperiam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet ab enim inventore illum voluptas, quaerat possimus aliquid natus? Corporis cumque quas sit. Ullam distinctio doloribus
              molestiae nihil reiciendis? Ut, sequi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis maxime porro, quibusdam iure provident esse nam, eius veritatis autem facilis officia dolorum iusto culpa eveniet corrupti facere deserunt
              ipsam voluptate. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi reiciendis, architecto aperiam nisi minus necessitatibus doloribus ad aut vitae libero impedit quidem illo mollitia obcaecati repudiandae temporibus voluptate
              quam! Nobis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et, cupiditate perferendis. Saepe illo quas ab quo veniam voluptas voluptatem ad architecto quia. Dolore quisquam molestias illo debitis voluptatum nesciunt repellendus.
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum suscipit animi sunt natus quae hic dolorem distinctio, laboriosam itaque dolorum vitae nihil cum voluptatem dolores ea, delectus repudiandae ducimus non. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
              amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat quo iste nulla magni et. Accusantium ex, voluptatibus blanditiis mollitia architecto accusamus necessitatibus quisquam tempora enim, ea, sint laborum quos adipisci?
            </p>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi doloribus fugit sunt at iste, dignissimos quam voluptas adipisci illo rerum maxime quis incidunt consequatur corporis velit maiores minima laboriosam. Iusto! Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur
              adipisicing elit. Odit beatae veniam sed eveniet molestiae deleniti modi nostrum, obcaecati perferendis sapiente similique totam voluptatem eos corporis minus libero, et cumque aperiam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
              elit. Amet ab enim inventore illum voluptas, quaerat possimus aliquid natus? Corporis cumque quas sit. Ullam distinctio doloribus molestiae nihil reiciendis? Ut, sequi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis maxime
              porro, quibusdam iure provident esse nam, eius veritatis autem facilis officia dolorum iusto culpa eveniet corrupti facere deserunt ipsam voluptate. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi reiciendis, architecto
              aperiam nisi minus necessitatibus doloribus ad aut vitae libero impedit quidem illo mollitia obcaecati repudiandae temporibus voluptate quam! Nobis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et, cupiditate perferendis. Saepe
              illo quas ab quo veniam voluptas voluptatem ad architecto quia. Dolore quisquam molestias illo debitis voluptatum nesciunt repellendus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum suscipit animi sunt natus quae hic dolorem
              distinctio, laboriosam itaque dolorum vitae nihil cum voluptatem dolores ea, delectus repudiandae ducimus non. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat quo iste nulla magni et. Accusantium ex, voluptatibus blanditiis
              mollitia architecto accusamus necessitatibus quisquam tempora enim, ea, sint laborum quos adipisci? Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi doloribus fugit sunt at iste, dignissimos quam voluptas adipisci illo rerum
              maxime quis incidunt consequatur corporis velit maiores minima laboriosam. Iusto! Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit beatae veniam sed eveniet molestiae deleniti modi nostrum, obcaecati perferendis sapiente similique
              totam voluptatem eos corporis minus libero, et cumque aperiam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet ab enim inventore illum voluptas, quaerat possimus aliquid natus? Corporis cumque quas sit. Ullam distinctio doloribus
              molestiae nihil reiciendis? Ut, sequi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis maxime porro, quibusdam iure provident esse nam, eius veritatis autem facilis officia dolorum iusto culpa eveniet corrupti facere deserunt
              ipsam voluptate. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi reiciendis, architecto aperiam nisi minus necessitatibus doloribus ad aut vitae libero impedit quidem illo mollitia obcaecati repudiandae temporibus voluptate
              quam! Nobis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et, cupiditate perferendis. Saepe illo quas ab quo veniam voluptas voluptatem ad architecto quia. Dolore quisquam molestias illo debitis voluptatum nesciunt repellendus.
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum suscipit animi sunt natus quae hic dolorem distinctio, laboriosam itaque dolorum vitae nihil cum voluptatem dolores ea, delectus repudiandae ducimus non. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
              amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat quo iste nulla magni et. Accusantium ex, voluptatibus blanditiis mollitia architecto accusamus necessitatibus quisquam tempora enim, ea, sint laborum quos adipisci?
            </p>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi doloribus fugit sunt at iste, dignissimos quam voluptas adipisci illo rerum maxime quis incidunt consequatur corporis velit maiores minima laboriosam. Iusto! Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur
              adipisicing elit. Odit beatae veniam sed eveniet molestiae deleniti modi nostrum, obcaecati perferendis sapiente similique totam voluptatem eos corporis minus libero, et cumque aperiam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
              elit. Amet ab enim inventore illum voluptas, quaerat possimus aliquid natus? Corporis cumque quas sit. Ullam distinctio doloribus molestiae nihil reiciendis? Ut, sequi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis maxime
              porro, quibusdam iure provident esse nam, eius veritatis autem facilis officia dolorum iusto culpa eveniet corrupti facere deserunt ipsam voluptate. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi reiciendis, architecto
              aperiam nisi minus necessitatibus doloribus ad aut vitae libero impedit quidem illo mollitia obcaecati repudiandae temporibus voluptate quam! Nobis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et, cupiditate perferendis. Saepe
              illo quas ab quo veniam voluptas voluptatem ad architecto quia. Dolore quisquam molestias illo debitis voluptatum nesciunt repellendus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum suscipit animi sunt natus quae hic dolorem
              distinctio, laboriosam itaque dolorum vitae nihil cum voluptatem dolores ea, delectus repudiandae ducimus non. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat quo iste nulla magni et. Accusantium ex, voluptatibus blanditiis
              mollitia architecto accusamus necessitatibus quisquam tempora enim, ea, sint laborum quos adipisci? Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi doloribus fugit sunt at iste, dignissimos quam voluptas adipisci illo rerum
              maxime quis incidunt consequatur corporis velit maiores minima laboriosam. Iusto! Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit beatae veniam sed eveniet molestiae deleniti modi nostrum, obcaecati perferendis sapiente similique
              totam voluptatem eos corporis minus libero, et cumque aperiam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet ab enim inventore illum voluptas, quaerat possimus aliquid natus? Corporis cumque quas sit. Ullam distinctio doloribus
              molestiae nihil reiciendis? Ut, sequi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis maxime porro, quibusdam iure provident esse nam, eius veritatis autem facilis officia dolorum iusto culpa eveniet corrupti facere deserunt
              ipsam voluptate. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi reiciendis, architecto aperiam nisi minus necessitatibus doloribus ad aut vitae libero impedit quidem illo mollitia obcaecati repudiandae temporibus voluptate
              quam! Nobis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et, cupiditate perferendis. Saepe illo quas ab quo veniam voluptas voluptatem ad architecto quia. Dolore quisquam molestias illo debitis voluptatum nesciunt repellendus.
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum suscipit animi sunt natus quae hic dolorem distinctio, laboriosam itaque dolorum vitae nihil cum voluptatem dolores ea, delectus repudiandae ducimus non. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
              amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat quo iste nulla magni et. Accusantium ex, voluptatibus blanditiis mollitia architecto accusamus necessitatibus quisquam tempora enim, ea, sint laborum quos adipisci?
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="main-right">RIGHT</section>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <p>© 2022 Company</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to debug your code, it seems that the `grid-template-rows` are affecting the content of your website.

Remove `grid-template-rows` on:

1. `#app main`
2. `#app main .main-left .text-logo`

because if you fix or specify some size in the row, your content will try to fit to that size, I don't use it when it comes to content creation sections.